# Multiple named router-outlet angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to display different views by child routes. For Example I want my template to hold multiple router-outlet

`Version: @angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7"`

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="route1"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="route2"></router-outlet>
```

In my router i want to specify the name of router.

As i saw in a question, the solution for this is to specify AuxRoute, but AuxRoute does not exist in this version.

```
{path: '/',        component: HomeComponent, as: 'Home'},
new AuxRoute({path: '/route1', component: Route1Component, as: 'Route1'}),
new AuxRoute({path: '/route2', component: Route2Component, as: 'Route2'})
```

While on angular 2 official website i found that it is possible to have multiple router, but i can't find any resource.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

`A template may hold exactly one unnamed <router-outlet>. The router supports multiple named outlets, a feature we'll cover in future.`

Comment: It's only partially implemented.

Comment: if it's only partially implemented why even mention it in the documentation? that just leads people down dead ends.

Answer (score 42):

Current version multiple-named `router-outlet` (for angular2 **RC.6^**) looks like this:

**Router configuration**

```typescript
const appRoutes: Routes = [{   
    path: 'home',
      component: HomeComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', component: LayoutComponent },
        { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component, outlet: 'route1' },
        { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component, outlet: 'route2' },
        { path: 'page3', component: Page3Component, outlet: 'route3' }
      ]
    }, {
      path: 'articles',
      component: ArticlesComponent,
      children: [
        { path: '', component: LayoutComponent },
        { path: 'article1', component: Article1Component, outlet: 'route1' },
        { path: 'article2', component: Article2Component, outlet: 'route2' }
      ]
    },  { 
      path: '', 
      redirectTo: '/home',
      pathMatch: 'full'
   }
];
```

**Template** within **Home** component:

```typescript
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="route1"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="route2"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="route3"></router-outlet>
```

And a **navigation** example from root component:

```typescript
constructor(router: Router) {
  router.navigateByUrl('/home/(route1:page1//route2:page2//route3:page3)');
}
```

Alternative way:

```typescript
<a [routerLink]="['/home', { outlets: {'route1':['page1'],'route2': ['page2'] }}]"></a>
```

Here's live [**Plunker Example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/biqCEQ1vHp6w6nVLNvK3?p=preview)

See also

- [Named Router Outlets in Angular 2](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2)

Comment: what about `<a [routerLink]="['/team/3(aux:/chat;open=true)']">Test</a>`, how should I set up link for multiple view? thanks

Comment: How would this: router.navigateByUrl('/home/(page1//route1:page2//route2:page3)');
}  look when using [routerLink]=""?

Comment: @Robin Gruschke I changed my answer

Comment: Is the blank one necessary?

Comment: If url is something like this :

    http://localhost:4200/route1/(outlet:article1)

then try following code to navigate by this :

    this.router.navigate([ '/route1', {outlets: { outlet: 'article1' }}]);