# Angular 4 Multiple Router Outlets

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet

```
<div *ngIf="!loggedIn" class="login">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>

<div *ngIf="loggedIn" class="main">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I have a login component (lives in `class="login"`) and a dashboard (lives in `class="main"`) component. I also have a register component that lives in the `class="login"` div. Now I know you're not suppose to use two `<router-outlet>` in the same template but if they're not showing at the same time, I don't see what the issue is. I've also tried to using the `[routersLink]="[{outlets}]"` method but it couldn't get it to work. Maybe because the `<router-outlet>` isn't shown due to the `*ngIf`.

So the issue is, when I go from the dashboard component, I see the login component. When I go from the login to the register component, the route updates but the register component doesn't fire. If I go straight from the login page to the register page, it routes and fires the register component.

Comment: You could probably solve it by using named outlets, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077355/changing-router-outlet-with-ngif-in-app-component-html-in-angular2)

Comment: I've actually tried that and spend 2 hours to no avail.

Comment: Put the div.login *inside* the login and register component templates. Put the div.main *inside* the dashboard template. And there you go: a single router outlet.

Answer (score 0):

I raise a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960568/moving-an-ng-template-between-2-viewcontainerrefs-occasionally-fails/50964963?noredirect=1#comment88957357_50964963) and found the following answer. See if this works for you,