# Moving an <ng-template> between 2 ViewContainerRefs occasionally fails

Tags: angular

In my stackblitz example, I've put a `<router-outlet>` inside of a `ng-template` tag so that I can move it between the mobile and desktop parts of the DOM when the window resizes. Eventually something goes wrong and this stops working correctly.

To observe the issue open the link below and resize the internal browser window. You should see the text switch between "Desktop" when `window.innerWidth > 600px` and "Mobile" otherwise. Keep resizing and eventually something goes wrong.

**What can be done to fix this issue?**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oavajy?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have omitted `break` in in **switch** statement, which is doesn't stop after reaching 'mobile' case. So if you put **console.log** in each method(loadMobileContent/loadDesktopContent), you will see after switching from mobile to desktop version each method is called:

```
  switch(newDevice){
      case 'mobile': this.loadMobileContent();
      case 'desktop': this.loadDesktopContent();
    }
```

Fix:

```
 switch (newDevice) {
      case 'mobile':
        this.loadMobileContent();
        break;
      case 'desktop':
        this.loadDesktopContent();
        break;
    }
```

Also change `moveRouterOutlet()` method to:

```
  moveRouterOutlet(fromOutlet: ViewContainerRef, toOutlet: ViewContainerRef): void {
    fromOutlet.clear();
    toOutlet.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
  }
```

[StackBlitzh Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o4ruhb)

Here is another solution with declarative approach with using **ngIf else** feature:

```
<div>
    <h1 *ngIf="device !== 'mobile' else tpl">Desktop</h1>
    <!-- <div #desktopOutlet></div> -->
</div>

<div>
    <h1 *ngIf="device !== 'desktop' else tpl">Mobile</h1>
    <!-- <div #mobileOutlet></div> -->
</div>

<ng-template #tpl>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxcdpu)

> Hey thanks for the effort. Problem with both solutions is that it will
>   reinitialize the component rendered through the . I
>   need to keep the component state as I switch viewports. that's why I'm
>   trying to detach it, not clear it.

Ok, then you can **detach** `ViewRef` from outlet and **insert** to another:

```
  moveRouterOutlet(fromOutlet: ViewContainerRef, toOutlet: ViewContainerRef): void {
    let detached = fromOutlet.detach();
    toOutlet.insert(detached);
  }
```

This will save the component state

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o4ruhb)

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort. Problem with both solutions is that it will reinitialize the component rendered through the `<router-outlet>`. I need to keep the component state as I switch viewports. that's why I'm trying to detach it, not clear it. `else` clears it as well.

Comment: @NateMay, fixed

Comment: I kiss you my friend! I was trying to figure out what to do with the `viewRef` that `detach()` returns

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what issue was there expect the text

> something works

was not behaving properly.

i have used `ng-container` instead of `ng-template` and it worked properly.

ng-template is used for structural directive like ng-if, ng-for and ng-switch. If you use it without structural directive, nothing happens and renders.

ng-container is used when you don't have a suitable wrapper or parent container.

hope this helps.

Comment: seems to work in stackblitz, but oddly, not in my local app

Comment: this is so strange! are you using any structural directive within it?

Comment: `ng-template is used for structural directive like ng-if, ng-for and ng-switch. If you use it without structural directive, nothing happens and renders.` Little wrong, because `ng-template` also used to create view(embedded)

Comment: for more details you can have a look here https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Comment: @HrishikeshKale I was following this example, https://netbasal.com/angular-2-understanding-viewcontainerref-acc183f3b682. I think there are use cases beyond structural directives.