# How to handle navigations when we have multiple outlets?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038733/806963 but I cant find a way to add params from the navigateByUrl method or a way to acomplish any of that in **Angular2 final**.

I have 2 router-outlers in 2 diffrent components.

1. `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside AppModule.
2. `<router-outlet name="account-information-outlet"></router-outlet>` inside AccountModule.

My code:

```
export const appRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(
  [
    {
      path: 'shop',
      loadChildren: 'app/modules/shop.module#ShopModule'(is not imporntent right now)
    },
    {
      path: 'account',
      loadChildren: 'app/modules/account.module#AccountModule' (related to the code below)
    },
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'shop',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    },
  ]);

export const accountRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: AccountInformationComponent,

    canActivate: [
      IsAnyUserLoggedInGuard
    ],
    children:[
      {
        path: 'profile/:key',
        component: ProfileComponent,
        outlet: "account-information-outlet"
      }
    ]
  }
]);
```

I tried to call this from AccountModule (AccountInformationComponent) : `this.router.navigate(['account/profile', parameter)` but it failed.

**Error:**

`Cannot match any routes: 'account/profile/-KUOW06DpH06D2rdvbLJ'`

Comment: what error you get? and from where you are calling router.navigate method???

Comment: I added the error and where I called if from. (Thought i added it in the first place)

Comment: `account/profile` refers to sibling component of `AccountInformationComponent` which is not define. profile is your child route and not the parent route.

Comment: `account/profile` refers to `ProfileComponent` with is defined. I'm sory I think that I'm not following. Can you explain it agian?