# Angular 6 with 2 router outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frameworks, router

how can I make sure to have at least 2 router-outlets and manage them at the routing level?
can link me a working jsfillde or stackblitz or similar?

edited re open problem

APP COMPONENT HTML

```
<main [@fadeInAnimation]="o.isActivated ? o.activatedRoute : ''">
    <router-outlet #o="outlet" name="main"></router-outlet>
    <router-outlet #o="outlet" name="second"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

APP MODULE

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

// components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

// models
import { Permissions } from '../app/models/permissions';

// guards
import { CanAccess } from '../app/guards/canaccess';
import { OtherComponent } from './components/other/other.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';

const permissions: Permissions = new Permissions();

const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { permission: permissions }, canActivate: [CanAccess], outlet: 'main' },
  { path: 'other', component: OtherComponent, data: { permission: permissions }, canActivate: [CanAccess], outlet: 'second' },
  { path: 'pageNotFound', component: PageNotFoundComponent, data: { permission: permissions }, canActivate: [CanAccess], outlet: 'main' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pageNotFound', pathMatch: 'full' },
];

export function appConfigFactory() {
  try {
      return () => true;
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(`catch load: ${e}`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    OtherComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute)
  ],
  providers: [
    CanAccess,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: appConfigFactory,
      deps: [],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

ERROR

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'home'

can view on editor
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ghusfs

thanks

Comment: You may find some interesting here: [Named router outlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038001/multiple-named-router-outlet-angular-2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may define parent child component to use multiple `router-outlets` like this.

```
{
        path: 'shop', component: ParentShopComponent, 
        children : [{
            path: 'hello', component: ChildShopComponent
        }]
    }
```

Your first `<router-outlet>` will be in app component & second in `ParentShopComponent` rest of components can lend in child level or parent.

But if your relationship is child parent than check this out [Named Router Outlets](http://onehungrymind.com/named-router-outlets-in-angular-2/)

Example

This is main Router OUtlet
    
      
    
These are named ones

```
<div class="columns">
  <md-card>
    <router-outlet name="list"></router-outlet>
  </md-card>
  <md-card>
    <router-outlet name="bio"></router-outlet>
  </md-card>
</div>
```

And here's how you use them

```
{ path: 'speakersList', component: SpeakersListComponent, outlet: 'list' }
```

Comment: is mandatory to create children component to have more router outlets?

Comment: No, if you don;t want to create you can use named router outlet check out the post

Comment: No it’s not mandatory, I just wrote 2 methods of doing multiple outlets.

Comment: can check my code beacuse not working. can help me to fix it?