# Angular Routing not working with different components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, angular-router

I have two components. Component A and Component B. I want to create a navigation system in component A that on click will load the appropriate element in component B.
I know within the same component we can use routerLink and router-outlet. But how can i achieve the same in my case ??

for example:

Component A

```
<a routerLink="/userHome"></a>
```

Component B

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And my routing module is :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {UserHomeMainBodyComponent} from './components/user-home-                
main-body/user-home-main-body.component';
import {UserNotificationsBodyComponent} from './components/user-    
notifications-body/user-notifications-body.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'userHome', component: UserHomeMainBodyComponent},
  {path: 'userNotifications', component:UserNotificationsBodyComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Can you please share your current routing configuration?

Comment: Added the post with routing configs.

Comment: Named outlets might be helpful in this case. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/38038733/10602679

Comment: NO, This thing will work when both the routerLink and router-outlet are used within same component. I am asking for them being in different components.